# Limitations on App images

Tags: android, svg, widget, google-play

Are there limitations to which image types you can use in your app?

When I try uploading an apk to the play store using either **only** `svg` or `webp`images I get the following error:

> Upload failed
>   You need to check the icon inside your APK because it is not valid.

Ofc I decompiled and checked that the icons actually were there.

*I know jpg / png is the way to go.*
But. Since Api 19 there is support on `webp` (which is...poorly documented and I could not find whether it was officially supported on all devices.)

Also, since Api 21 there is official `svg` support. This one is documented.

So I made 3 flavors of my app (it's a small flashlight widget consisting of 2 images, [Source Code](https://github.com/bleeding182/minimalist-flashlight))

- `png` default
- `webp` 19+ (smaller than png)
- `svg` 21+ (even smaller ;))

Now while installing works fine and the app is running, I can only upload the png version, getting the error mentioned above on my other flavors.

I did not find any constraints on which image formats you were to use, besides some notions that you should use `png / jpg`.

Since android gradle plugin 1.3 supports svg to png conversion at compile time, making a flavor for 21+ with nothing but svgs seems tempting.
What are the limitations?

Comment: Did you find answer to this question?

Comment: @NinjaCoder Yes. It seems like you have to include a png. I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the Google Play Developer Support, asking whether the launcher / app icon needs to be of the `png` file format.

Their answer was the following:

> [...] I can confirm you are correct that the launcher icon does need to use a png and not a svg. For more information please see the following:
>   https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html

So it seems like you will always have to at least include one png file (the app icon) in your apk.